# p2p соединение без внешнего ip

Tags: сеть

Возьмём к примеру скайп. Пока взаимодействие идёт через сервер — всё ок: у него есть внешний ip, у меня нету, я создаю tcp-соединение и получаю возможность принимать пакеты. Но теперь я хочу позвонить Пете, у которого тоже отсутствует внешний ip, и, как известно, звонки в скайпе производятся напрямую.

Вопрос: каким образом я создаю соединение с Петей, не имеющем внешний ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

взаимодействие через сервер не идет. оно идет p2p, сервер лишь помогает установить это соединение. если обе стороны за NATом, то соединение устанавливается через супер-ноды (через любого пользователя скайп, с внешним ip).

Answer (score 1):

Вот что вытащил через Google минут за 10. Если ошибаюсь, сильно не бейте.

1. [Википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype)

   Skype может маршрутизировать звонки через компьютеры других пользователей. Это    позволяет соединяться друг с другом пользователям, находящимся за NAT или брандмауэром, однако создаёт дополнительную нагрузку на компьютеры и каналы пользователей, подключённых к Интернету напрямую.
2. [Skype Architecture](http://www.mjalali.com/blog/?p=10)

   Call signalling and media transfer

   If both caller and receiver are on public IPs and receiver is in the buddy list of the caller, then they establish a call through a direct TCP connection with each other and transfer media using UDP.

   If the caller or receiver is behind a port-restricted NAT then they establish a call through a few packets initially transferred between caller, receiver , SN and other hosts [Refer to [3] for more details] and a UDP connection is established between the caller and receiver which is used to transfer media as well.

   If caller and receiver are behind a UDP-restricted firewall they will need a relay (node) in between to establish TCP connection to and then the traffic (including media) will go through from one side to the other.

Из этого следует, что для инициализации соединения нужен внешний IP. Далее можно обмениваться UDP пакетами со своим адресом отправителя и адресом получателя *получаемым после NAT*. Этот адрес будет известен промежуточному узлу с внешним IP, через который устанавливается соединение. Видимо он передается в качестве данных (Skype протокола ?) клиенту при инициализации соединения.

IMHO как-то так.